# Doesn't grails run-app create a war?

Tags: grails

Doesn't a grails run-app create a WAR file(exploded) in the embedded Tomcat Container? If so what is the difference between grails run-app and grails run-war command?

Is it possible to view the web app directory under the embedded Tomcat Directory after the execution of grails run-app command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *grails-app* command starts an embedded Tomcat server and configures its context paths so that it can look up everything it needs from their original filesystem paths. Therefore there is no single place where everything would be gathered as would be when running an exploded web application archive.

Comment: so do you mean to say the exploded war is the one under the grails project itself. right?

Comment: Yes, but it will also include the plugin directories as aliases. If you check *catalina.base* system property in a Grails application started with *run-app*, you'll notice that it points to your Grails project dir.

Answer (score 2):

No, run-app doesn't create a war. It starts the Tomcat server and configures it programmatically as an exploded war.

Comment: May be I need to rephrase the question. Doesn't create an exploded WAR file? If so where is the location. Is the target directory under the grails project